# Get inputText value of selected row using wrapper class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I need help getting the apex:InputText value of a selected row using wrapper class. I can get all the values but no the qty entered in this column. I tried to create a list<> that holds the values but it didn't work.  Can anybody please help me? I will really appreciate any help.

Page:

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapRODetailsList }" var="servWrap" id="table1"  title="Selected Services" >
       <apex:column >
         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!servWrap.selected }" id="ParentChecked" >
          <apex:actionsupport action="{!SelectedRODetails}" event="onchange" rerender="table1"  />
         </apex:inputCheckbox>

         </apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!servWrap.serv.Id}" />
         <apex:column value="{!servWrap.serv.Name}" />
         <apex:column >
           <apex:inputText id="enteredValue"  />
         </apex:column>

 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Controller:

```
  public void SelectedRODetails() {

  //This list will hold the selected roe values 
    selectedRODetails = new List<NRProducts__c  >();

    for(wrapRODetails wrapRODetailsObj : wrapRODetailsList ) {

        if(wrapRODetailsObj.selected == true) {
            selectedRODetails.add(wrapRODetailsObj.serv);

        }
    }

}
```

Wrapper:

```
public class wrapRODetails{
    public NRProducts__c  serv {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    public String EnteredValue{get;set;}

    public wrapRODetails(NRProducts__c  s) {
        serv = s;
        selected = false;

    }

}
```

This is how I get the values of the selected row

```
  //here for loop to get selected values
  for (NRProducts__c  row : selectedRODetails) 
  {
    //example 
    (id)row.get('Id')

  }
```

Comment: Do you get all the selected rows correctly onchange of the select checboxes? and your problem is that newly entered values are not reflected in the records right?

Comment: navD87, yes you are correct. I don't know how to store the inputText value so I can use it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Mark Pond's answer, to access the EnteredValue in a NRProducts__c loop, you can do the following,

```
public void SelectedRODetails() {

    //This list will hold the selected roe values 
    selectedRODetails = new List<NRProducts__c  >();

    //this will hold the entered value for each NPRProducts__c
    Map<Id, String> enteredValueOfEachSelectedNPRProduct = new Map<Id, String>();

    for(wrapRODetails wrapRODetailsObj : wrapRODetailsList ) {

        if(wrapRODetailsObj.selected == true) {
            selectedRODetails.add(wrapRODetailsObj.serv);
            enteredValueOfEachSelectedNPRProduct.put(wrapRODetailsObj.serv.Id, wrapRODetailsObj.EnteredValue);
        }
    }

}
```

then in your NPRProducts loop

```
  for (NRProducts__c  row : selectedRODetails) {
      String enteredVal = enteredValueOfEachSelectedNPRProduct.get(row.Id);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You guys made my day! I learned something new today :) thanks ...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your `<apex:inputText` tag isn't bound to any members on the wrapper class, so the data that you input on screen isn't persisted on the wrapper instance.

Changing the markup to bind the text field to your `String` named `EnteredValue` on the wrapper class should do the trick.

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:inputText id="enteredValue" value="{!servWrap.EnteredValue}"  />
</apex:column>
```

You would then have access to the EnteredValue while looping the wrapper list.

```
if(wrapRODetailsObj.selected == true) {
    selectedRODetails.add(wrapRODetailsObj.serv);

    // get the data from the wrapper member
    system.debug(wrapRODetailsObj.EnteredValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark,  thank you for our response!  I will test it and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Mark,   the system.debug is displaying the right EnteredValue :), but how can I retrieve the value in the for loop? so I can use it   `
  for (NRProducts__c  row : selectedRODetails) 
  {
    //get enteredvalue here
    

  }`

Comment: 'EnteredValue' is a property of 'wrapRODetails' not 'NRProducts__c', so you can't directly access 'EnteredValue' while looping through NRProducts. In your previous loop where you create the selectedRODetails list, you can also create a map that maps the NRProducts__c Id of the selected row to the entered value. You can use that map in your ` for (NRProducts__c row : selectedRODetails) { //get enteredvalue here }` loop

Comment: navD87, thank you for your response! I am a bit confused,  can you please help with this? I will truely appreciate it